# AS3: a non systematic XML loading bug

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, debugging, download

As said in my title, I have a XML loading problem. In my code, I load some XML files for showing the texts included in these XML files. But these texts aren't displayed in the Flash online software.

The language changes with the user choice. It's for every text in the software. When you begin to use the software, after a location files loading and a data conversion for a new format in the database, you arrive on a main menu, not included in the previous version.
There are several problems with this bug :

1. **It's a non systematic bug.** When I deploy application six times, I
   would have this problem around only once. I must do deployments for
   one hour for seeing the bug again. The bug seems to arrive only in
   an "old version → new version" deployment, too.
2. **In the software, the bug goes away by itself after from five to
   ten minutes.** You can change language. Before the ten minutes, the
   concerned texts will be empty only in the default language. After
   the ten minutes, there isn't the bug anymore.
3. **The concerned texts are in new XML tags, not included in the
   previous version.**

Because this is a non systematic bug, it's very laborious to debug this problem (new informations after one hour full of deployments…). Among others, I try to force software to load texts again before the main menu display. Without success…

Unfortunately, I can't send my code, because I haven't my code with me now. I will be able to realize my tests in some hours.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a caching issue. The simplest solution is to load your XML with a timestamp querystring so that the browser never caches it:

```
new URLRequest("data.xml?timestamp=" + new Date().time);
```